# Remove id div only from first parent

Tags: javascript, function, parent-child, removechild

I want to remove div "id = child" only from div "id = parent" but not to remove div "id = child" outside of "id = parent"???
Of course, there will be more elements with the same id inside parent anda outside.

```
<style>
#parent{ 
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
    background-color: blue; 
}
#child{ 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: red; 
}
</style>
```

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="child"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()" >click</button>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
   document.getElementById("child").remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should not have 2 elements with the same id, how about using class?

Comment: There cannot be more than one elements with the same id. Use some class and you can select the first element with that class through query selector.

Comment: I know it can be done with class but I need an id, some idea?

Comment: If you need an id, you can use an id with my answer, but again, there cannot be more than one elements with the same id. If they did, then the DOM will only recognize the id of the first element in the DOM. The second element with the same id will be treated as if there is no id for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your html to have a class and not id for more than one elements.

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="child"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()" >click</button>
```

And then, use javascript to get the first element of the class like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];//the selector will select an 
//array of all elements with the same class, so we specify the first by denoting [0]
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);//and then remove that element
}
</script>
```

Edit:
If you want to do it with an id, change the code from

`var element = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];`

to

`var element = document.getElementById("child");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it through the parent.childNodes if you don't want to change your html

```
function myFunction() {
   const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
   parent.childNodes.forEach(el => el.id == 'child' && el.remove());
}
```